# Receiving weird errors while trying to use classes in project

Tags: c++, class, header, project

I am trying to use classes in a project and I am receiving this error:

> cl.exe /nologo /W3  /Zi /D_DEBUG    /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include" /c -.cpp /Foobj\Debug-.obj
>
> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option 'main.cpp'
>
> cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename

Not sure what to do to fix this, all of my project files are in one directory though. My files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grum.h"
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     grum gru;
     return 0;
}
```

Class.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grum.h"
using namespace std;
grum::grum()
{
    cout << "testing" << endl;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef GRUM_H
#define GRUM_H
class grum
{
public:
    grum();
};
#endif // GRUM_H
```

This code was simply supposed to print out "testing".

Comment: Your program isn't wrong - it's related to your command. Apparently `-main.cpp` is parsed as an *option*, not a *value* by `cl.exe`.

Comment: I tried replacing main.cpp with another source file now, but now there are other errors: LNK2019: unresolved external symbols; and there are many of them.

Comment: @Arquon One question -- since you're using Visual Studio, why are you using the command-line instead of the IDE to build your program?  And even if you wanted to use the command-line, the IDE tells you what the command-line should be (in the Project Settings).

Comment: Im not using Visual Studio, im using its compiler. Im using CodeBlocks.